# Godot 4.2 connecting a signal from an instantiated child to the parent using C#

Tags: c#, godot

How is a signal that is emitted from a child scene connected to the parent node?

In my code, the delegate is created in a script of an instantiated scene

```
[Signal]
public delegate void OnKnobChangeEventHandler(float val);
```

Then the signal is emitted

```
EmitSignal(nameof(OnKnobChangeEventHandler), value); //value is a float
```

Trying to connect this signal. to the parent errors are thrown on the second and third parameters of the Connect method

```
private float _heading = 30;
private float _course = 30;
private Label _lbl_heading;
private Label _lbl_course;
public override void _Ready()
{
_lbl_heading = GetNode<Label>("lbl_heading");
_lbl_course = GetNode<Label>("lbl_course");
_courseKnob = GetNode<Node>("Bezel/KnobHeading");
_headingKnob = GetNode<Node>("Bezel/KnobCourse");
_courseKnob.Connect("OnKnobChange", this, OnCourseKnobSignalReceived);

}
private void OnCourseKnobSignalReceived(float value)
{
_course += value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax that worked:

```
_courseKnob.Connect("OnKnobChange", new Callable(this, MethodName.OnCourseKnobSignalReceived));
```

also:  When the signal is emitted, the EventHandler suffix must be removed

The solution aided by this website:  [Godot Documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-connect)